# Does The Dialog ID change?

Tags: winforms, winapi

Does the Dialog ID change from one machine to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot change, your code would never be able to find the dialog template back in the resources.

Comment: So you never change to make all our win32 software work? That's admirable... :)
(+1 for the correct answer and for the funny typo :) )